# Having two foreign keys into a single column

Tags: sql-server-2008, polymorphic-associations

I have a problem in creating a table with a column that has two foreign Key relationships. Let me explain in detail.

I have three tables:

- `Table A` - columns `ID (primary key), Name`
- `Table B` - columns `ID (primary key), Name`
- `Table C` - columns `ID, Name, Detail`

In `C.Detail` I have to store data from both other tables (A.ID & B.ID). So I tried to add two foreign key into the column `C.Detail`. During insert operation in `Table B` the following error occurs, and the same error message occurs while trying to insert data into `Table A`.

> "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_C_A". The conflict occurred in database "X", table "dbo.A", column
>   A.ID."

Please, can anyone help us to rectify this problem? We don't want to add two columns in `table C` for two foreign keys.

Hopefully waiting for the reply.

Comment: If you have **two foreign keys**, you need to have **two foreign key columns** in TableC - anything else doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to introduce two new columns in Table C. (i.e AID and BID). 
Create Foregin key on this news columns.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think the way to go about doing this is to create a "parent" table for A and B that has A_B_parent.id(primary_key) and then have A and B both have foreign keys on their id to the parent table.  Then C can also have a foreign key to the parent table.

This obviously ends up being really complex, so the better solution might just be to programmatically enforce the constraint rather than using foreign keys and then put a comment on the table.